# Dropdown com imagens em navbar bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou tendo um problema de disposição de um dropdown de imagens em bootstrap, dropdown este que esta dentro de um navbar

código html:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><!--------- START Navbar --------->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"><!-- START Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
            </div><!-- END Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"><!-- START Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">            
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                            <img src="../../../images/icon/share-icon.png" 
                            alt="share"/>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width:80px;">
                            <li style="width:50px;">                                    
                                <a href="#"><img src="../../../images/icon/twitter-icon.png" 
                                alt="twitter"/></a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="width:50px;">                                    
                                <a href="#"><img src="../../../images/icon/facebook-icon.png" 
                                alt="facebook"/></a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="width:50px;">                                    
                                <a href="#"><img src="../../../images/icon/tumblr-icon.png" 
                                alt="tumblr"/></a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- END Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        </div>
    </nav><!--------- END Navbar --------->
```

o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Adicionei Paddings as imagens(50px) para que o ela tenha o exato tamanho do navbar(50px) mas sem sucesso (fica uma moldura cinza em volta), e o tamanho do espaço dos icones tambem nao fica com 50px (tamanho da imagem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por default .dropdown-menu tem um min-width de 160px. Você vai precisar alterar um pouco o estilo sobrescrevendo o estilo do Bootstrap.

[Eu simulei um examplo aqui.](http://www.bootply.com/8KXADmi6JX)

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Ilá ,@fricks modifiquei sua resposta para atuar somente sobre o dropdown de icones (irei ter outro futuramente), adicionei o css diretamente no html mas irei colocar em arquivo separado posteriormente, editei a pergunta

Comment: as imagens não ficam centralizadas

Comment: Vc quer deixar a ul dropdown com 80px? E as imagens com 50px e centralizar elas?

Comment: Sim desejo centralizar as imagens

Comment: Basta adicionar text-align:center na li

Comment: Não funcionou acabei de testar, testei também class=text-center

Comment: Veja no exemplo http://www.bootply.com/8KXADmi6JX, está funcionando.

Answer (score 0):

Exemploutilizando `font-awesome+css`:

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/yqk6xfn2/1/)

Para adicionar novos icones:
exemplo:

`<i class="fa fa-{NOMEDOICONE}"></i>`

[Documentação font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

Comment: copy and paste code..